# Storing input of type time into the database

Tags: php, html, database, post, time

i have aa input of type time in my form, i'm using angular, i'm posting the input as it , without any modifications.

i'm trying to store the input in the database with format HH:MM , for example when i enter input : 05:10 AM , i'm storing it into three fileds in the database : varchar,date, time

the value stored in varchar field:`1970-01-01T03:10:00.000Z` ,
in date field: `1970-01-01`,
in time field: `00:00:00`

all what i need is to store the input in the time filed as 05:10 !! if i enter PM for example 10:00PM to be stored as 22:00 , this worked with me when i used regular form post, but never working when i use angular post ($http.post) ,, any solution ?!!

Comment: You are always free to preprocess this before inserting

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $d = date("h:i:sa");
 $q = "INSERT INTO table_name (column) VALUES ($d);
?>
```

Comment: thank you, stay with me plz, i stored the input in $my , ok ?! how i can apply the function on $my ?

Comment: $my = $f[0]['in_time']; here i'm receiving the time from the input.

Comment: why are you accessing them via arrays ?

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.